# La función getComputedStyle retorna vacío los valores de css a usar dentro del plugin table2export

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy armando una tabla para exportarla con el plugin table2export.js pero al generar el excel no se generan los estilos de fondo, borde o color.
He probado que la función getComputedStyle() sí retorna los estilos de un elemento si lo uso directamente en el dom, pero no desde el script de table2export.

- table2export v1.1.2
- jquery v3.2

Mi código:

```
<script>
$('#btnExport').on('click', function (event) {
        var table = '',
            rows = $('.card .e-row')
        table += '<table class="table table-bordered tb-exportable table2excel_with_colors">';
        $.each(rows, function(rid, ritem) {
            var cells = $(ritem).find('.e-cell'),
                cellHeaders = '<tr class="tb-row">',
                cellBodys = '<tr class="tb-row">';
            $.each(cells, function(cid, citem) {
                var label = $(citem).find('.e-label'),
                    text = $(citem).find('.e-control'),
                    colspan = $(citem).attr('colspan') ?? '';
                    is_head = $(citem).data('head') ? 'background="rgb(255, 165, 0)" backgroundColor="rgb(255, 165, 0)"' : '';
                cellHeaders += (label.length ? '<td '+is_head+' colspan="'+colspan+'" s="51">'+label.text()+'</td>' : '');
                cellBodys += (text.length ? '<td colspan="'+colspan+'">'+text.text()+'</td>' : '');
            })
            cellHeaders += '</tr>';
            cellBodys += '</tr>';
            table += (cellHeaders + cellBodys);
        })
        table += '</table>';
        $('.card-body').append(table)

        var tbexp = $('.tb-exportable');
        
        var preserveColors = (tbexp.hasClass('table2excel_with_colors') ? true : false);
        tbexp.table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExl",
            sheetName: "cc",
            filename: "tb-export",
            fileext: ".xls",
            exclude_img: true,
            exclude_links: true,
            exclude_inputs: true,
            preserveColors: preserveColors
        });

        $('.tb-exportable').remove()

        return table;
    })
</script>
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví modificando el plugin y obteniendo el estilo con la función de jquery .css('border'). Por si alguien lo necesita.

Línea 87 del archivo jquery.table2excel.js

```
<script>
// Preserve background and text colors on the row
if(e.settings.preserveColors){
  var _q = $(q),
  color = _q.css('color');
  bgcolor = _q.css('background-color');
  borderLeft = _q.css('border-left');
  borderRight = _q.css('border-right');
  borderTop = _q.css('border-top');
  borderBottom = _q.css('border-bottom');
  textAlign = _q.css('text-align');

  additionalStyles += (bgcolor ? "background-color: " + bgcolor + ";" : "");
  additionalStyles += (color ? "color: " + color + ";" : "");
  additionalStyles += (borderLeft ? "border-left: " + borderLeft + ";" : "");
  additionalStyles += (borderRight ? "border-right: " + borderRight + ";" : "");
  additionalStyles += (borderTop ? "border-top: " + borderTop + ";" : "");
  additionalStyles += (borderBottom ? "border-bottom: " + borderBottom + ";" : "");
  additionalStyles += (textAlign ? "text-align: " + textAlign + ";" : "");
</script>
```